# Need help with openfeint integration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, openfeint

I am trying to integrate openfeint with my app.. though it's not actually the integration I am stuck on, successfully able to open the leader-board, but actually the development flow. I mean what is the least we need to do... When to submit score and how? Achievements are bit ambiguous:( .. was searching all around then figured out it'd be the best way to get exact answers to my question. Kindly help.

EDIT:
My main question is that what least should be done in an app to say that it's openfeint integrated.

Comment: It would help if you rephrased your text into a couple of actual questions we can answer instead of ambiguous statements.

Comment: @0x90 Thanks for suggestion.. hope the EDIT would clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a minimum, achievements and leaderboards. But I'd recommend using OpenFeint because it solves a specific problem for you, rather than to simply check off a feature. If you don't have a clear idea, you may not have a clear idea of the game's overall design. If so, you might be better served to come back to the integration half-way in, after you've made more decisions.

Then you can say things like "Oh, I have three different play modes. I'll make a leaderboard for each." Or "This level is really hard – I'll definitely award an achievement if they complete it in x time." And so on.

But you should really reach out to OpenFeint's dev support if you have questions like this – they'll be able to give you good advice on integration.